# assist with including a file when creating a csv - PHP

Tags: php

have a button that goes to a php file with the headers to create csv; and this all works.  I can even "hard code" in a database connection and get stuff from database as i am building csv output and that all works.  the only issue i am having is trying to inlude an external file for the database connection.  I have included files a lot in my php scripts and never had a problem.  But trying to do it within the headers of my csv seems to make it crash...

here is my code:

```
include_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/jba_sched6/config_db_files/jba_config.php' );

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=jba_export_games.csv");


echo $date.",";
echo $time.",";
echo $div_names[$div_id].",";
echo $team_names[$v_team].",";
echo $team_names[$h_team].",";
echo $gym_names[$gym_id].",\n";

exit();
```

So just thew some of my echos in there - but that is all working - so just need help on how to inlude the file.  If I manually write in the db connection it all works fine.

All the best,  G

Comment: Define "makes it crash" ? Is it possible that the include is generating any kind of output to the browser, including a single space or a new line, etc?   You can't have headers sent after any output to browser.  Check your error log for exact error message, or turn on error reporting if needed.

Comment: thanks so much for your comment ivan - turning on errors was the key in fixing this, it uncovered more than i thought; but once i could see the errors - there was nothing that i could not handle...